# schema.methods is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have been trying to create a method on my user schema in mongoose, however it keeps saying method is not a function and I have no idea why. I am fairly new to mongoose and express, and I'm pretty sure I have my files set up currently so I don't know what could be causing this issue. As a last attempt, I tried switching to arrow functions , but that didn't work either.

user routes file

```
const router = require("express").Router();
let user = require("../models/user_model");
const Joi = require("@hapi/joi");
// GET dreams
// POST dreams
// DELETE dreams
// UPDATE dreams
router.route("/").get((req, res) => {
  console.log(user.addType());
  res.send("hello this is a users page");
});
```

user model file

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      trim: true,
      min: 3
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      min: 6
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);
userSchema.methods.addTypes = function() {
  console.log("woof");
};
userSchema.methods.joiValidate = data => {
  let Joi = require("@hapi/joi");
  const schema = {
    username: Joi.string()
      .min(6)
      .required(),
    password: Joi.string()
      .min(6)
      .required()
  };
  return schema.validate(data);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE!** Other than having typo on your code, you also need to create an instance of your model ('user'). You cannot just call the function of the model.

```
let user = new user({ // Create an instance first
    username: 'Tester',
    password: '12345678'
})
console.log(user.addType())
```

you declared

```
addTypes()
```

Cheers

Comment: its still not working, it still says addTypes() is not a function.

Comment: Hi @MysteriousShadow I have updated the answer. You need to create an instance of the model instead of just using the function of the model.